# StaggeredGridView cannot pass an instance - The getter 'viewModel' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, staggered-gridview

Working with `StaggeredGridView`, I cannot pass an additional instance like the `viewModel` below to a Material class, this is the error I get:

> Error: The getter 'viewModel' isn't defined for the class
> '_MainPageState'.

```
Material Items(IconData icon, String heading, Color cColor) {
    return Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (heading ==
                ('Text')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); // <- The error
            } else if (heading ==      /* ^^^^^^^^^ */
                ('Text1')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); // <- The error
            }                          /* ^^^^^^^^^ */
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child:
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            icon,
                            color: cColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(    
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                          child: Text(
                            heading,
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget loadMainPage(ViewModel viewModel) {
    return StaggeredGridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          Items(
              Icons.add,
              ('Text'),
              Colors.green),
          Items(
              Icons.add,
              ('Text1'),
              Colors.red),
        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        ],
      );
  }
```

Comment: Add your full code of `_MainPageState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

The problem is that you're attempting to use the `viewModel` variable in the `Items` method but the `viewModel` variable is not available to the `Items` method.

The `viewModel` variable is available in the `loadMainPage` method but it is not being passed into the `Items` method.

### Solution:

You need to:

- add the `ViewModel` object as a parameter for the `Items` method and
- pass the `viewModel` variable to the `Items` method used in your `loadMainPage` method.

Update the `Items` method to this:

```dart
Material Items(IconData icon, String heading, Color cColor, ViewModel viewModel) { // <- Update here
    return Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (heading ==
                ('Text')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); 
            } else if (heading ==         
                ('Text1')) {
                  showMainDialog(context, viewModel); 
            }                             
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child:
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            icon,
                            color: cColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(    
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                          child: Text(
                            heading,
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

And update the `loadMainPage` method to this:

```dart
  Widget loadMainPage(ViewModel viewModel) {
    return StaggeredGridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        children: <Widget>[
          Items(
              Icons.add,
              ('Text'),
              Colors.green, 
              viewModel, // <- Update here
          ),
          Items(
              Icons.add,
              ('Text1'),
              Colors.red, 
              viewModel, // <- Update here
          ),
        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 150.0),
        ],
      );
  }
```